# Magento 2: save product review

Tags: magento2

I am working on a **Magento 2** extension that will send a message to me when a new product review is written. I've tried to create an observer, but it never seems to work.

In `ets/events.xml`, I have this:

```
<event name="review_save_after">
    <observer 
        name = "jeroen_update_product_review"
        instance = "Jeroen\ReviewIntegration\Observer\ProductReview" />
</event>
```

In `Jeroen\ReviewIntegration\Observer\ProductReview`:

```
namespace Jeroen\ReviewIntegration\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProductReview implements ObserverInterface
{
     protected $_storeManager;
     protected $_request;

     public function __construct(
         \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
         \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     ) {
         $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
         $this->_request = $request;
     }

     public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
     {
          return 'test';
     }
}
```

This always gives a a blank page after a new review is written (and after the status of the review is updated). Can anyone find out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the magento logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies! I found out that it was just a caching error. De code needed to be recompiled before it worked. Thanks anyway for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Plugin to achieve any functionality after review save

> di.xml file

```
<type name="Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post">
    <plugin name="After_save_product_review"
                type="Module\Custom\Plugin\UpdateReviewSaveAfter" />
</type>
```

> Plugin file

```
namespace Module\Custom\Plugin;

class UpdateReviewSaveAfter
{
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post $subject,
        $result)
    {       
        //your fuctionality

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you set enough memory_limit in php.ini

php.ini values are:

post_max_size = 1024M

upload_max_filesize = 1024M

memory_limit = 3G

max_execution_time = 500